# cassandra node not starting due to ERROR [main] 2018-01-09 04:08:58,733 CassandraDaemon.java:705 - Exception encountered during startup

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra node is not starting and throws the below exception.

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Unknown type datakeyspace.identificationtype
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.CQL3Type$Raw$RawUT.prepare(CQL3Type.java:768) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.CQL3Type$Raw.prepareInternal(CQL3Type.java:537) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.Types$RawBuilder$RawUDT.lambda$prepare$2(Types.java:313) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.Types$RawBuilder$RawUDT.prepare(Types.java:314) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.Types$RawBuilder.build(Types.java:263) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTypes(SchemaKeyspace.java:979) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:950) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:928) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:916) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:91) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:81) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:262) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:476) ~[dse-core-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:599) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:93) [dse-core-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you have done to get this error. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: can you please provide the details of what you were doing and exactly at which point you encountered above error?

Comment: we are in the process of evaluating cassandra for a project usecase. A keyspace has been dropped from cqlsh commandline.In parallel there was a request from the java service to create the keyspace with the same keyspace name. After this incident cassandra nodes were still up showing the above mentioned exception in the logs. Due to some administration activities on the server all ( 3 nodes, 2 in dc1 and 1 in dc2) were brought down. now I see the mentioned exception during startup of each node. Please advise if there is a way to overcome this exception

Comment: after over 2 years, same scenario here with 3.11.6
before we brought it down 'describe keyspaces' showed the affected keyspace, but 'use' or 'drop' were saying InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace '<keyspace_name>' does not exist" or ConfigurationException: Cannot drop non existing keyspace respectively

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the type definition in system_schema is corrupted. One can workaround that by copying the type definition from a healthy node to the faulty node. You will find the schema type in the Cassandra data folder: `<cassandra>/data/system_schema/types-*`.

The issue is listed already here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13739